# (C++) Counting inversions in arrays from text file, one array per line?

Tags: c++, arrays

I need to count the number of inversions in arrays stored in a text file, such as:

```
1 4 5 3 2
2 1 4 3
6 2 4 1 3 5
```

I have written two functions to count the inversions, but they take arrays as arguments, like this:

```
int merge_sort(int array[], int inferior_limit, int superior_limit)
```

My question now is how to read the text file, one line at a time, and store each line into an array to count the inversions. I thought of using a 2D array, but the number of columns varies in each line. I have also considered using `getline`, as in:

```
    while(std::getline(inFile,numbers))
```

However, I don't know what to follow it with so that it doesn't read all the numbers. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is it a requirement that you use C-style arrays? You're programming in C++ after all, why not use `std::vector`, etc?

Comment: Your question is not posed well, you are asking about counting inversions, which you apparently know how to do. What you should have (not) asked is reading lines from a file. I'm saying (not) because that would likely quickly end up as a duplicate question.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [sstream](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/sstream/stringstream/) to read the array from string

```
#include <sstream>

while(std::getline(inFile,numbers)) {
  std::vector<int> arr;
  std::stringstream ss(numbers);
  int temp;
  while(ss >> temp) arr.push_back(temp);
  // First argument of merge_sort would be &arr[0]
  // size of array would be arr.size();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example how the assignment can be done. You can use ideas behind the code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <numeric>
#include <iterator>
#include <functional>

int main() 
{
    std::string record;

    while ( std::getline( std::cin, record ) )
    {
        std::istringstream is( record );
        std::vector<int> v( ( std::istream_iterator<int>( is ) ),
                            std::istream_iterator<int>() );

        if ( v.empty() ) continue;                     

        bool increase = true;

        auto n = std::inner_product( std::next( std::begin( v ) ), std::end( v ), 
                                     std::begin( v ), size_t( 0 ), 
                                     std::plus<size_t>(), 
                                     [&] ( int x, int y ) -> size_t
                                     {
                                        bool current = increase;
                                        return ( ( increase = x >= y ) ^ current );
                                     } );

        std::cout << n << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

If the file contains records

```
1 4 5 3 2
2 1 4 3
6 2 4 1 3 5
```

then the output will be

```
1
3
4
```